# CodeIgniter CSRF never works on first attempt

Tags: php, codeigniter, csrf

I have a strange problem and i dont find the solution. I activated csrf in CodeIgniter config file. When i try to login, the first attempt always fails. All the next attempts works. It works on my local MAMP, but when i push it on my Webserver, i have that strange problem. The error that i get: 
The action you have requested is not allowed.

My config.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://www.xy.de/test1/';
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
```

My view:

```
<?= form_open('login/connect' , ' class="login-form" '); ?>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input required type="text" name="fUsername" class="form-control rounded-input" placeholder="<?= $this->lang->line('username_or_email_placeholder'); ?>" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input required type="password" name="fPassword" class="form-control rounded-input" placeholder="******" aria-label="password" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            </div>
            <div class="w-100 text-center">
                <button class="loginButton" type="submit" name="fLogin"><span><?= $this->lang->line('login'); ?></span></button>&nbsp;
                <a href="<?= base_url() ?>recover/request" id="forgotPassword"><?= $this->lang->line('forgot_password'); ?>?</a>                    
            </div>
        <?= form_close() ?>
```

Controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        if($this->LoginModel->isLoggedIn()){
            if($this->LoginModel->isUserSuperAdmin($this->session->idUser)){
                redirect("cms/dashboard");
            }else {
                redirect("cms/profile");
            }
        }else{
            $this->load->view("cms/login", array("title" => SITE_TITLE . " - " . $this->lang->line("login")));
        }
    }

public function connect()
    {
            $login = trim($this->input->post("fUsername"));
            $password = $this->input->post("fPassword");
            if ($this->LoginModel->login($login, $password)) {
                if ($this->LoginModel->isUserSuperAdmin($this->session->idUser)) {
                    redirect("cms/dashboard");
                } else {
                    redirect("cms/profile");
                }
            }

        redirect("cms");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hash is regenerating, you should use what class is providing, not a static one.

Try this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?>" value="<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>" />
```

Comment: The HTML Code that i posted above was from Inspect Element. I replaced it with my HTML Code from my view file. The csrf input field is generated by form echo

Comment: You set True the global xss filter in Config file

Comment: @GillesFeierstein do you have any other form in the same page? or any post ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Try to Form call like this and not need

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_test_name" value="60bcd04d35e8e0ce9508a474e9d704da">
```

It's automatically set into form 
Your form call is :

```
<form action="https://www.xy.de/test1/login/connect" class="login-form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

---------------------------
---------------------------
</form>
```

You may try to use it

```
<?php echo form_open('login/connect', array('class' => 'login-form')); ?>
-----------------------------
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Hope it's work. I use it and work
Thank You